# Equality between pointers in a function c++

Tags: c++, pointers

Can you please tell me what's wrong when making equality between to pointers in a function. Let's see this example:

```
void fun(int *array1)
{
    int array2[5];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        array2[i]=3;
    }
    array1=array2;
}


int main(){
    int x[5]; int n=5;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    x[i]=i; // --------> x[i]=i;
    }

    fun(x); //--------> x[i]=3

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    cout<< x[i]<<" "; //-------> x[i]=i?????????? I expected x[i]=3;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't assign arrays like that (what you're doing is pointing array1 to a temp array; it doesn't affect x).  Just use array1 in fun's loop instead (I'd pass the size to the function instead of hardcoding that 5 too).

Comment: @Peter Huene why not write the answer?

Comment: Eh, laziness :)  Besides, I like giving other people the easy points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void fun(int *array1)
{
    int array2[5];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        array2[i]=3;
    }
    array1=array2; // **HERE**
}
```

When this function returns, `array2` no longer exists. So even if this did return the value of `array1` to the caller, the caller would just have a pointer to an array that no longer existed.

Of course, it doesn't even do that. `array1=array2;` sets the `array1` variable to point to `array2`. But they're both local variables, so this has no effect on the caller anyway.

Perhaps you wanted:

```
 memcpy(array1, array2, sizeof(array2));
```

But this is C++, you should be using a sensible container like [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Answer (score 2):

You create a new array with the int[5] in your fun function I think you intend to do:

```
/**
  * not every array is 5 items long, thus it is unsafe
  */

void fun(int *array1)
{
    int* array2 = array1;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        array2[i]=3;
    }
}
```

now int* array2 points to the array you call in the main function